# Can I push to Heroku using a non-Cedar-supported app?

Tags: heroku

My app only uses PHP and SQLite.

I get this error:

> Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be a able to use PHP, there is a [PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) — although it’s not very well documented on the Heroku site. Looking at [its detect script](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect), it is checking for an `index.php` file. Does your app have one? If not you’ll need to create one, if only so that it’ll be detected as a PHP app.

If your app still isn’t being detected as a PHP app, you could try explicitly [specifying the buildpack to use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) with a config var:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

A bigger problem is that you won’t be able to use SQLite on Heroku. Even if you were to create your own buildpack that added the relevant SQLite libraries, the read-only filesystem would mean it’s of little use. You should look into using [Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/what-database-does-heroku-use) (or possibly MySQL using an add-on).